# Maximum values of $\frac{{\sin A}}{A} + \frac{{\sin B}}{B} + \frac{{\sin C}}{C}$, then $\left[ {\frac{{2\pi M}}{3}} \right]$

Tags: trigonometry

> For any acute $\Delta ABC$, let $M$ denote the maximum values of $\frac{{\sin A}}{A} + \frac{{\sin B}}{B} + \frac{{\sin C}}{C}$, then $\left[ {\frac{{2\pi M}}{3}} \right]$ is equal to ________

(where
$[.]$ denotes greatest integer function and angle $A,B,C$ are measured in radians)

$M = \frac{{\sin A}}{A} + \frac{{\sin B}}{B} + \frac{{\sin A}}{C}$

$\frac{a}{{\sin A}} = \frac{b}{{\sin B}} = \frac{c}{{\sin C}} = 2R$

$M = \frac{a}{{2RA}} + \frac{b}{{2RB}} + \frac{c}{{2RC}}$

$M = \frac{1}{{2R}}\left( {\frac{a}{A} + \frac{b}{B} + \frac{c}{C}} \right)$

$\frac{{\frac{1}{{2R}}\left( {\frac{a}{A} + \frac{b}{B} + \frac{c}{C}} \right)}}{3} \ge {\left( {\frac{1}{{8{R^3}}}\left( {\frac{a}{A}.\frac{b}{B}.\frac{c}{C}} \right)} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

$\frac{1}{{2R}}\left( {\frac{a}{A} + \frac{b}{B} + \frac{c}{C}} \right) \ge 3{\left( {\frac{1}{{8{R^3}}}\left( {\frac{a}{A}.\frac{b}{B}.\frac{c}{C}} \right)} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

How we will approach from here

Comment: I think that proceeding further will give minimum value of M , not maximum